# Excel Formula Select all text between (but not including) two characters and replace all _ with a space?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

In cell A1

I have text like AB_CD_(EF_G_H)_1234

I am trying to write a formula that selects the text after (but not including) the ( character and before (but not including) the ) character and then replaces the _ character with a space so the end result would be EF G H

I am entering the formula in Cell B1

I have managed to get EF_G_H using

`=MID(LEFT(A1,FIND(")",A1)-1),FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1))`

and I can remove the _ and replace with a space using

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")`

but I cant get the two to combine into a single formula

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1),"_"," ")
```

or, using your formulas:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(LEFT(A1,FIND(")",A1)-1),FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),"_"," ")
```

Comment: Thank you Ron. Both work perfectly.

Comment: @Kenny Glad to help. If my answer satisfies your problem, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as accepted. You can read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.